# How is ex implemented in vim?

Tags: vim, vi, ex

Now I am reading a book on `sed` and `awk` and to learn the history needed to use `ed` and `ex` commands.

I thought for a `vim` user on Arch Linux, there is no need to install other packages but I found that `ex` is not included in the `gvim`, `vim-runtime` packages.

I guess the way `vi` and `vim` implements `ex` are a bit different, but how?

Comment: Arch Linux doesn't do an "alternatives" system like Debian, so if one package provides `ex`, another can't. Since [`ex` is provided by the `vi` package](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/vi/), the `vim` packages can't provided it. You can always run `vim -e` to run Vim in ex-mode (or just make an alias of `vim -e`).

Comment: Also see: https://vimhelp.org/vi_diff.txt.html?#vi-differences

Comment: @muru Thx. Now it seems my question is off-topic :(